# How to publish Angular app to gh-pages? It gives me error

Tags: angularjs, git, github, github-pages

I have a simple Angular application. I tried to publish it on git hub following these steps:

1. git checkout --orphan gh-pages
2. git add .
3. git commit -m "Message"
4. git push origin gh-pages

But when want to access the link, it says page not found 404

Doesn't git-hub support angular application? If so, what am I doing wrong???

Here is the structure of my project

```
MyApp
   --css
   --html5lightbox
   --images
   --js
      controller.js
   --pages
   index.html
   index2.html
```

It is just a simple front-end application!

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, github static pages work with any javascript framework. Your problem should be another. What link are you trying to access?

Comment: @ItaloAyres Unfortunately, I cannot give the github link as it is corporate link. Anyway you will not have the access to the git hub link. So you say I do everything correct, is it?

Comment: without actually giving us the url, what is the url that you were going for? i.e.  http://<username/orgname>.github.io/<projectname>/whateverpathyouareusing

Comment: @g19fanatic Here is the link generated by github.   https://<orgname>/pages/<username>/SunshinePrototype. I also upload on a personal server but cannot find the index.html too. It works for simple  HTML and Javascript applications but not with Angular

Comment: I believe you're not going to the correct location in your browser. A great example of ng being used in gh-pages is angular-ui/bootstrap.  https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/       https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/gh-pages/index.html

Answer (score 0):

GitHub is [having issues right now](https://status.github.com/) which is delaying updates to your remote branch; try to access your page again after they're resolved!

Comment: So, my code is right for publishing angular app, is it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to go a different url for your project. A 404 says that where you're going doesn't exist

try to go to

```
  http://<orgname>.github.io/<MyAppRepoName>/
```

Otherwise, your steps as shown are correct to create the gh-pages branch. So long as your directory is setup as mentioned, the pages should show up.